# How can I center a Angular mat-expansion-panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. I modified a different stackblitz to add this as a test:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acdxje-8bz7tq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css,styles.css,app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Code I am using:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="Expand" style="width: 80%; text-align: center">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title style="text-align: center"> Test </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `text-align: center` with `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly inspected the code I saw that the header was using flex

```
mat-expansion-panel-header .mat-content {
  justify-content: center;
}
```